# Merge n sorted iterators

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, reinventing-the-wheel, iterator

Over the weekend I was curious about efficiently merging multiple sorted iterators together, and for them to be in sorted order.
This is quite like a challenge on [HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/merge-two-sorted-linked-lists/problem):

> You’re given the pointer to the head nodes of two sorted linked lists. The data in both lists will be sorted in ascending order. Change the next pointers to obtain a single, merged linked list which also has data in ascending order. Either head pointer given may be null meaning that the corresponding list is empty.

I may have cheated a bit by printing, rather than returning the items. However I don't mind that much about the HackerRank challenge.

I managed to do this in about \$O(3l)\$ space and \$O(l(2+n))\$ time. So \$O(l)\$ and \$O(ln)\$. Where \$l\$ is the amount of lists, and \$n\$ is the amount of data.

```
import operator
import functools

def from_iterable(fn):
    @functools.wraps(fn)
    def inner(*args):
        return fn(args)
    inner.from_iterable = fn
    return inner


@from_iterable
def merge(sources):
    sources = {
        id_: iter(source)
        for id_, source in enumerate(sources)
    }
    values = {}
    for id_, source in list(sources.items()):
        try:
            values[id_] = next(source)
        except StopIteration:
            del sources[id_]

    by_value = operator.itemgetter(1)
    while sources:
        id_, minimum = min(values.items(), key=by_value)
        try:
            values[id_] = next(sources[id_])
        except StopIteration:
            del values[id_], sources[id_]
        yield minimum


def iter_nodes(node):
    while node is not None:
        yield node.data
        node = node.next


def MergeLists(headA, headB):
    vals = merge.from_iterable(iter_nodes(l) for l in (headA, headB))
    print(' '.join(str(i) for i in vals), end='')
```

A bit overkill for the HackerRank challenge. But that wasn't the main reason for doing it.
Any and all reviews are welcome.

Comment: A priority queue of pairs `(value, id)` instead of a dictionary gives \$O(n \log l)\$ time complexity.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. There are no docstrings. What do these functions do? What arguments do they take? What do they return?
2. Decorators are normally named after the *effect they have on the decorated function*. For example [`@functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) adds an LRU cache to a function; [`@unittest.skip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.skip) causes a test case to be skipped, and so on.

   The effect of `@from_iterable` is that it converts the arguments into a tuple and passes that tuple as a single argument to the original function. I would not have guessed this functionality from the name; in fact I would have guessed the reverse (that it would convert a single iterable argument to individual arguments).
3. It was established in comments that the intention of this decorator is to transform a function into a pair of functions like [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) (where the original function becomes available under the latter name, and the new function under the former name).

   The trouble with this is that `chain` was a mistake. If we only had `chain.from_iterable`, then we would not need `chain`, because we could just make a tuple: we'd write `chain.from_iterable((arg1, arg2, ...))` instead of `chain(arg1, arg2, ...)`. This is a trivial change to calling convention (just two parentheses) that does not need another function to support it. (For example, it would be ridiculous to have `sorted` and `sorted.from_iterable`.)

   The Python developers were constrained by backwards compatibility to leave `chain` alone, and so the only thing they could do was add another function. I don't think they intended it to be a pattern to be followed (it's certainly not used anywhere else in the standard library). To this day, Python programmers looking for a "flatten" function are surprised to find that it already exists in the standard library under an obscure name.

   Note that the code in the post does not actually use `merge`, it only uses `merge.from_iterable`. So the obvious thing to do would be to write `merge` so that it takes an iterable, and avoid the need for the `@from_iterable` decorator and its associated confusion.
4. Since `headA` and `headB` are not used independently of each other, you could change the calling convention for `MergeLists` so that it took an arbitrary number of linked lists, like this:

   ```
   def merge_linked_lists(*lists):
       "Merge multiple sorted linked lists."
       return merge(map(iter_nodes, lists))
   ```
5. The expression:

   ```
   str(i) for i in vals
   ```

   can be written:

   ```
   map(str, vals)
   ```

   Or if you prefer the comprehension, then consider improving the name of the loop variable. The name `i` is conventionally used for an *index*, but here we are not iterating over indexes, but over values, so `v` or `value` would be clearer.
6. The code in `merge` does not use the built-in function [`id`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id), so there is no need to respell the variable as `id_` in order to avoid shadowing the built-in.
7. The function `merge` maintains two data structures. The dictionary `source` maps a source id to an iterator over the corresponding source, and the dictionary `values` maps a source id to the value at the front of the corresponding source. The code would be simplified if the two data structures were combined into one, like this:

   ```
   def merge(iterables):
       "Merge sorted iterables."
       entries = {} # Map from id to [front value, id, iterator].
       for id, it in enumerate(map(iter, iterables)):
           try:
               entries[id] = [next(it), id, it]
           except StopIteration:
               pass
       by_value = operator.itemgetter(1)
       while entries:
           id, entry = min(entries.items(), key=by_value)
           value, _, it = entry
           yield value
           try:
               entry[0] = next(it)
           except StopIteration:
               del entries[id]
   ```
8. The runtime bottleneck is the call to [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) to find the entry with the smallest value. This takes time proportional to the number of remaining iterables, that is, \$O(l)\$.

   We can improve this to \$O(\log l)\$ if we keep the entries in a [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)), using the [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) module:

   ```
   from heapq import heapify, heappop, heapreplace

   def merge(iterables):
       "Merge sorted iterables."
       entries = []          # Heap of [front value, id, iterator].
       for id, it in enumerate(map(iter, iterables)):
           try:
               entries.append([next(it), id, it])
           except StopIteration:
               pass
       heapify(entries)
       while entries:
           value, _, it = entry = entries[0]
           yield value
           try:
               entry[0] = next(it)
               heapreplace(entries, entry)
           except StopIteration:
               heappop(entries)
   ```

   This improves the overall runtime to \$O((n + l)\log l)\$.
9. This is already built into Python as [`heapq.merge`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge). It's worth taking a look at the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/heapq.py#L314) — the code in §8 above is a simplified version of this.