# Sorting songs with the ability to save and resume partial sorts

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, sorting, coroutines

I listen to a lot of music (~4k h/y) and managing thousands of songs is a bit of a challenging.
To improve my listening experience I want to better organize my collection.
One thing I want to do is sort my songs, as then I can do cool things with dynamic playlists.
For example, I want to listen to songs I don't like as much, but I don't want back-to-back Ls.

---

When sorting the songs I want to continuously answer the dead simple question "which is better A or B?"
As I have moved enough songs through playlists for one life-time.
Additionally if I were to listen to each song once all the way through then sorting would take 2 weeks.
As such, whilst most (maybe all) of Python's stdlib ordering functions support objects which only define `__lt__`,
things like `sorted` don't support saving state part way through.
I like listening to music but being wired for 2 weeks straight, stressing about any outage, doesn't sound like a fun experience.
(And unfortunately my server is experiencing sporadic hard freezes.)

As such I have have 4 constraints:

1. Work well with unstable comparisons.
2. Only ask which is better -- `__lt__`.
3. Support saving and resuming partial sorts.
4. Defer `__lt__` comparison to the consumer of the sort algorithm allowing for use in a web app.

   **NOTE**: I have one user (me), so threading is *not* a concern.

I have solved each:

1. I have tested the rough outline of the algorithm (binary tree binning and 'heap' merging) through simulation.
   And the performance was good.

   The simulation was somewhat flawed as a first quarter value could sometimes be found in the third or fourth quarter.
   However the overall delta from the correct value was very good at ~3%.
   If I decreased the randomness of the perceived value the list would just be sorted in perfect order.
   So basically any algorithm will probably be alright.
2. Only using `__lt__` is simple.
3. I've added some fairly basic metaprogramming in `Sort` to support loading and dumping values to JSON by defining the type annotations on the class.
   So for the most part saving and resuming is just `sort.dumps()` and `Sort.loads(...)`.

   The complicated part is having an algorithm which supports resuming from an arbitrary save point.
   As such the very basic function `bisect.bisect` has to balloon up in size and complexity.
4. At first I was going to define an `advance` method to get the next comparison.
   However, I found the `__iter__` like pattern unintuitive to model within a class.
   And I found I kept wanting to pass a `cmp` callback as a quick hack.

   As such I moved to the coroutine pattern to generate the values.
   The pattern is fairly rare.
   In Python coroutines are probably 99% the `async` bespoke flavour.
   Or at least 99% of the results seem to be `async` ones when googling.
   As such I would appreciate a more 'high level' opinion on the approach.
   Have I shoehorned a solution where a better approach could exist?

   Additionally I found coroutines a little annoying to interact with.
   So I've defined a couple of methods to split the values from the output and be stored in a mutated list.
   Very dirty, but really seems like the simplest solution to the problem.
   I kept writing the same 'groupby' like code to split the coroutine in two.
   Sometimes *twice* in the same method.

   The entire approach is very mutable, and so is a lot harder to reason with.
   So again, nothing more than a high level critique could be interesting.

---

I'm going to be honest I haven't properly tested or documented the code.
I'm only really writing the code to facilitate ranking songs, and is mostly a write once and discard project.
The approach is somewhat novel and could be a learning experience for a better approach.
Here's a brief explanation of each sort class.

Helpers:

- `Sort` is the base class to help cut down code size of the subclasses.
- `SortValues` is a `Sort` composing a list.
- `SortValuesCache` caches values to ensure no data loss. `Sort.run__values` can't be saved/loaded.
- `SortBisect` is a reimplementation of `bisect`.
- `SortFirsts` gets the first item of each `Sort` -- useful for building the 'heap' in the `SortMerge` classes.

  ```py
  def sort_firsts(*sorts: Iterator[T]) -> tuple[tuple[T, Iterator[T]], ...]:
      return tuple(
          (value, sort)
          for sort in sorts
          if (value := next(sort, None)) is not None
      )
  ```
- `Sorted` overwrites `from_list` to have a simple standardized way to sort the items.

  - If the list has 15 or less items we `SortMergeAll.from_list`.
  - Otherwise we delegate to `SortBin.from_list`.

Merge:

- `SortMergeSource` builds the 'heap' and then delegates to `SortMerge`.
- `SortMerge` is a [`heapq.merge`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/187368) except using a binary tree not a heap. (I'm too lazy to write a heap)
- `SortMergeAll` overwrites the default `from_list` implementation from `SortMerge` to be stable across saving and loading. (Again I'm too lazy to rewrite the iterator approach)

Binary Tree Binning:

- `SortBin_` builds the binary tree and bins for `SortBin`.
- `SortBin`:

  - Has a binary tree. (I found a very small tree of size 7 to be the most effective)
  - Bin values by going through the (small) binary tree.
  - Sort the bins by the provided `Sort` class. (By default `Sorted`)
  - Merge the sorted `Sort`s into one output.

TL;DR: If the amount of items we want to sort is 15 or fewer, then we perform a very basic `heapq.merge` using a binary tree rather than a heap. Otherwise We use a small (size 7) binary tree to bin values, which we then recursively sort using both the `heapq.merge` and binary tree binning algorithms.

---

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import enum
import functools
import json
import math
import random
from typing import Any, Callable, ClassVar, Generator, Generic, Iterable, Iterator, Literal, ParamSpec, Self, TypeAlias, TypeVar, TypedDict, cast

T = TypeVar("T")
T0 = TypeVar("T0")
T1 = TypeVar("T1")
T_contra = TypeVar("T_contra", contravariant=True)
TIter = TypeVar("TIter", bound=Iterator[Any])
P = ParamSpec("P")


class DSort(TypedDict):
    __name__: str
    kwargs: dict[str, Any]


class JSONSortDecoder(json.JSONDecoder):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        kwargs.setdefault("object_hook", type(self).object_hook)  # type: ignore
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def object_hook(d: dict[str, Any]) -> Any:  # type: ignore
        if ("__name__" in d
            and "kwargs" in d
        ):
            cls = Sort.MODELS[d["__name__"]]
            if d["kwargs"] is None:
                return cls
            else:
                return cls(**d["kwargs"])
        return d


class JSONSortEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o: Any) -> Any:
        if isinstance(o, Sort):
            return o._dump()
        if issubclass(o, Sort):
            return {"__name__": o.__name__, "kwargs": None}
        return super().default(o)


class SortState(enum.Enum):
    COMPARE = enum.auto()
    VALUE = enum.auto()


ASortRunValue: TypeAlias = Generator[tuple[Literal[SortState.VALUE], T], None, None]
ASortRunCompare: TypeAlias = Generator[tuple[Literal[SortState.COMPARE], tuple[T, ...]], bool, None]
ASortRun_: TypeAlias = Generator[tuple[Literal[SortState.COMPARE], tuple[T0, ...]] | tuple[Literal[SortState.VALUE], T1] | tuple[SortState, tuple[T0, ...] | T1], bool | None, None]
ASortRun: TypeAlias = ASortRun_[T, T]


class Sort(Generic[T0, T1]):
    MODELS: ClassVar[dict[str, type[Sort[Any, Any]]]] = {}

    def __init_subclass__(cls) -> None:
        super().__init_subclass__()
        cls.MODELS[cls.__name__] = cls  # type: ignore

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        args = ", ".join(
            f"{key}={getattr(self, key)!r}"
            for key in self.__annotations__
        )
        return f"{type(self).__module__}.{type(self).__qualname__}({args})"

    def _dump_value(self) -> dict[str, Any]:
        return {
            key: getattr(self, key)
            for key in self.__annotations__
        }

    def _dump(self) -> DSort:
            return {"__name__": type(self).__name__, "kwargs": self._dump_value()}

    def dumps(self) -> str:
        return json.dumps(self, cls=JSONSortEncoder)

    @classmethod
    def loads(cls, data: str) -> Self:
        return json.loads(data, cls=JSONSortDecoder)

    @classmethod
    def from_list(cls, data: list[T]) -> Sort[T, T]:
        raise NotImplementedError(f"{cls.__module__}.{cls.__qualname__}.from_list has not been defined")

    @functools.cached_property
    def run(self) -> ASortRun_[T0, T1]:
        raise NotImplementedError(f"{type(self).__name__}.run has not been defined")

    def _run__reset(self) -> ASortRun_[T0, T1]:
        def inner() -> ASortRun_[T0, T1]:
            yield obj # type: ignore
            raise ValueError(f"Cannot use {type(self).__name__}.run after using {type(self).__name__}.run__group")

        it = self.run
        obj = object()
        self.run = inner()
        obj_ = next(self.run)
        assert obj is obj_
        return it

    @functools.cached_property
    def run__group(self) -> Iterator[tuple[Literal[SortState.VALUE], ASortRunValue[T1]] | tuple[Literal[SortState.COMPARE], ASortRunCompare[T0]]]:
        def inner() -> ASortRun_[T0, T1]:
            nonlocal state, value
            assert state is not None
            STATE = state
            while state is STATE:
                ret = yield state, value
                try:
                    state, value = it.send(ret)
                except StopIteration:
                    state = None
                    return

        it = self._run__reset()
        state: SortState | None
        try:
            state, value = next(it)
        except StopIteration:
            return
        while state is not None:  # type: ignore
            yield state, inner()  # type: ignore

    @functools.cached_property
    def run__values(self) -> list[T1]:
        return []

    @functools.cached_property
    def run__compare(self) -> ASortRunCompare[T0]:
        output = self.run__values
        for state, obj in self.run__group:
            if state is SortState.VALUE:
                for _, item in obj:
                    output.append(item)  # type: ignore
            else:
                yield from obj  # type: ignore


class SortBisect(Sort[T, int]):
    values: list[T]
    value: T
    lo: int
    hi: int

    def __init__(
        self,
        values: list[T],
        value: T,
        lo: int = 0,
        hi: int | None = None,
    ) -> None:
        self.values = list(values)
        self.value = value
        self.lo = lo
        self.hi = len(self.values) if hi is None else hi

    @functools.cached_property
    def run(self) -> ASortRun_[T, int]:
        while self.lo < self.hi:
            mid = (self.lo + self.hi) // 2
            is_wanted = yield SortState.COMPARE, (self.value, self.values[mid])
            if is_wanted:
                self.hi = mid
            else:
                self.lo = mid + 1
        yield SortState.VALUE, self.lo

    def update_heaps(self, *heaps: tuple[list[T0], Callable[[], T0]]) -> ASortRunCompare[T]:
        yield from self.run__compare
        i, = self.run__values
        self.values.insert(i, self.value)
        for heap, value in heaps:
            heap.insert(i, value())


class SortFirsts(Sort[T0, T1]):
    sorts: list[Sort[T0, T1]]
    values: list[T1]

    def __init__(
        self,
        sorts: list[Sort[T0, T1]],
        values: list[T1],
    ) -> None:
        self.sorts = sorts
        self.values = values

    @classmethod
    def from_list(cls, data: list[T]) -> SortFirsts[T, T]:
        return cls([SortValues(data)], [])  # type: ignore

    @functools.cached_property
    def run(self) -> ASortRun_[T0, T1]:
        for sort in self.sorts[len(self.values):]:
            try:
                state, value = next(sort.run)
            except StopIteration:
                continue
            while state is not SortState.VALUE:
                ret = yield state, value
                try:
                    state, value = sort.run.send(ret)
                except StopIteration:
                    pass
            self.values.append(value)  # type: ignore


class SortValues(Sort[T, T]):
    data: Iterable[T]

    def __init__(self, data: Iterable[T]) -> None:
        self.data = iter(data)

    @classmethod
    def from_list(cls, data: list[T0]) -> SortValues[T0]:
        return cls(data)  # type: ignore

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"<{type(self).__name__}>"

    def _dump_value(self) -> dict[str, Any]:
        return {"data": list(self.data)}

    @functools.cached_property
    def run(self) -> ASortRun_[Any, T]:
        for value in self.data:
            yield SortState.VALUE, value


class SortValuesCache(Sort[T0, T1]):
    sort: Sort[T0, T1]
    values: list[T1]
    repeat_values: bool

    def __init__(self, sort: Sort[T0, T1], values: list[T1], repeat_values: bool = False) -> None:
        self.sort = sort
        self.values = values
        self.repeat_values = repeat_values

    @classmethod
    def from_list(cls, data: list[T]) -> SortValuesCache[T, T]:
        return SortValuesCache(SortValues(data), [], False)

    @functools.cached_property
    def run(self) -> ASortRun_[T0, T1]:
        for value in self.values:
            yield SortState.VALUE, value
        sort = self.sort.run
        try:
            state, value = next(sort)
            while True:
                if state is SortState.VALUE:
                    self.values.append(value)  # type: ignore
                input = yield state, value
                state, value = sort.send(input)
        except StopIteration:
            pass


class SortMerge(Sort[T, T]):
    heap: list[tuple[T, int, Sort[T, T]]]
    bisect: SortBisect[T] | None

    def __init__(self, heap: list[tuple[T, int, Sort[T, T]]], bisect: SortBisect[T] | None = None) -> None:
        self.heap = heap
        self.bisect = bisect

    @classmethod
    def from_list(cls, data: list[T0]) -> Sort[T0, T0]:
        # return cls.from_sources(*[
        #     SortValues([d])
        #     for d in data
        # ])
        return cls.from_intense(data)

    @classmethod
    def from_sources(cls, *sources: Sort[T, T]) -> SortMergeSource[T]:
        return SortMergeSource(SortFirsts(list(sources), []), None, [], cls)

    @classmethod
    def from_intense(cls, values: list[T]) -> Sort[T, T]:
        def inner(lo: int, hi: int) -> Sort[T, T]:
            if lo + 1 == hi:
                return SortValues([values[lo]])
            mid = (lo + hi) // 2
            return cls.from_sources(
                inner(lo, mid),
                inner(mid, hi),
            )

        if not len(values):
            return SortValues([])  # type: ignore
        return inner(0, len(values))

    @functools.cached_property
    def run(self) -> ASortRun[T]:
        SENTINEL = object()

        heap = self.heap
        if self.bisect is not None:
            yield from self.bisect.update_heaps((heap, lambda: heap.pop(0)))  # type: ignore  # Type "bool | None" cannot be assigned to type "bool"
            self.bisect = None
        while heap:
            yield SortState.VALUE, heap[0][0]
            new_value: T = cast(T, SENTINEL)
            try:
                state, value = next(heap[0][2].run)
            except StopIteration:
                pass
            else:
                while state is not SortState.VALUE:
                    ret = yield state, value
                    try:
                        state, value = heap[0][2].run.send(ret)
                    except StopIteration:
                        break
                else:
                    new_value = value  # type: ignore
            if new_value is SENTINEL:
                heap.pop(0)
            else:
                heap[0][0] = new_value  # type: ignore
                self.bisect = SortBisect([v for v, _, _ in heap[1:]], new_value)
                yield from self.bisect.update_heaps((heap, lambda: heap.pop(0)))  # type: ignore  # Type "bool | None" cannot be assigned to type "bool"
                self.bisect = None


class SortMergeAll(SortMerge["T"]):
    @classmethod
    def from_list(cls, data: list[T0]) -> Sort[T0, T0]:
        return cls.from_sources(*[
            SortValues([d])
            for d in data
        ])


class SortMergeSource(Sort[T, T]):
    sources: SortFirsts[T, T]
    bisect: SortBisect[T] | None
    heap: list[tuple[T, int, Sort[T, T]]]
    sort: SortMerge[T] | None
    sort_type: type[SortMerge[T]]

    def __init__(
        self,
        sources: SortFirsts[T, T],
        bisect: SortBisect[T] | None,
        heap: Iterable[tuple[T, int, Sort[T, T]]],
        sort_type: type[SortMerge[T]],
        sort: SortMerge[T] | None = None,
    ) -> None:
        self.sources = sources
        self.bisect = bisect
        self.heap = list(heap)
        self.sort = sort
        self.sort_type = sort_type

    @classmethod
    def from_list(cls, data: list[T0], sort_type: type[SortMerge[T0]] = SortMerge) -> SortMergeSource[T0]:
        return cls(SortFirsts([SortValues(data)], []), None, [], sort_type)  # type: ignore

    def _dump_value(self) -> dict[str, Any]:
        return {"sources": self.sources, "bisect": self.bisect, "heap": self.heap, "sort": self.sort, "sort_type": self.sort_type}

    def _dump(self) -> DSort:
        # return super()._dump()
        if self.sort is None:
            return super()._dump()
        else:
            return self.sort._dump()

    @functools.cached_property
    def run(self) -> ASortRun_[T, T]:
        if self.sort is None:
            yield from self.sources.run
            heap: list[tuple[T, int, Sort[T, T]]]
            heap = [list(a) for a in zip(self.sources.values, range(len(self.sources.sorts)), self.sources.sorts)]  # type: ignore
            heap = heap[len(self.heap):][::-1]

            heap_ = self.heap
            if self.bisect is None and heap:
                self.bisect = SortBisect([v for v, _, _ in heap_], heap[-1][0])
            while self.bisect is not None:
                yield from self.bisect.update_heaps((heap_, heap.pop))  # type: ignore
                if heap:
                    self.bisect = SortBisect(self.bisect.values, heap[-1][0])
                else:
                    self.bisect = None

            by_id = dict(zip(self.sources.values, self.sources.sorts))  # type: ignore
            self.sources = SortValues.from_list([])  # type: ignore
            heap_ = [
                [value, i, by_id[value]]
                for value, i, _ in heap_
            ]
            self.sort = self.sort_type(heap_)  # type: ignore
        yield from self.sort.run


class SortBin_(Sort[T, T]):
    data: list[T]
    tree: SortValuesCache[T, T]
    bins: list[list[T]]
    bisect: SortBisect[T] | None

    def __init__(
        self,
        data: list[T],
        tree: SortValuesCache[T, T],
        bins: list[list[T]],
        bisect: SortBisect[T] | None = None,
    ) -> None:
        self.data = data
        self.tree = tree
        self.bins = bins
        self.bisect = bisect

    @classmethod
    def from_list(
        cls,
        data: list[T0],
        *,
        sort: Sort[T0, T0] = SortValues,  # type: ignore
        depth: int = 2,
    ) -> SortBin_[T0]:
        assert 1 <= depth
        # Sigma(2 ** n)
        amount = 2 ** (depth + 1) - 1
        ## random.seed(42401)  # needed for Sorted to be stable
        indexes = random.sample(range(len(data)), min(amount, len(data)))
        return cls(  # type: ignore
            data,
            SortValuesCache(
                sort.from_list([
                    data.pop(i)
                    for i in sorted(indexes, reverse=True)
                ]),
                [],
                False,
            ),
            [[] for _ in range(amount + 1)],
        )

    @functools.cached_property
    def run(self) -> ASortRunCompare[T]:  # type: ignore
        yield from self.tree.run__compare
        output = self.tree.run__values
        if (self.bisect is None
            and self.data
        ):
            self.bisect = SortBisect(output, self.data.pop())
        while self.bisect is not None:
            yield from self.bisect.run__compare
            output_ = self.bisect.run__values
            self.bins[output_[0]].append(self.bisect.value)
            if self.data:
                self.bisect = SortBisect(output, self.data.pop())
            else:
                self.bisect = None


class SortBin(Sort[T, T]):
    bins: SortBin_[T]
    sort: type[Sort[T, T]]
    mergers: list[SortValuesCache[T, T]]
    merge: Sort[T, T] | None

    def __init__(
        self,
        bins: SortBin_[T],
        sort: type[Sort[T, T]],
        mergers: list[SortValuesCache[T, T]],
        merge: Sort[T, T] | None = None,
    ) -> None:
        self.bins = bins
        self.sort = sort
        self.mergers = mergers
        self.merge = merge

    @classmethod
    def from_list(
        cls,
        data: list[T0],
        *,
        sort: Sort[T0, T0] = SortValues,  # type: ignore
        sort_tree: Sort[T0, T0] | None = None,  # type: ignore
        depth: int = 2,
    ) -> SortBin[T0]:
        return cls(  # type: ignore
            SortBin_.from_list(data, sort=sort if sort_tree is None else sort_tree, depth=depth),  # type: ignore
            sort,  # type: ignore
            [],
            None,
        )

    @functools.cached_property
    def run(self) -> ASortRun_[T, T]:
        if self.merge is None:
            yield from self.bins.run  # type: ignore
            if self.mergers:
                yield from self.mergers[-1].run__compare  # type: ignore
            for i in range(len(self.mergers), len(self.bins.bins)):
                values = self.bins.bins[i] + ([] if len(tree := self.bins.tree.values) <= i else [tree[i]])
                self.mergers.append(SortValuesCache(self.sort.from_list(values), [], False))
                yield from self.mergers[-1].run__compare  # type: ignore
            self.merge = SortMerge.from_sources(*[
                SortValues(m.values)
                for m in self.mergers
            ])
        yield from self.merge.run


class Sorted(Sort[T, T]):
    _sort: SortValuesCache[T, T]

    def __init__(
        self,
        _sort: SortValuesCache[T, T],
    ) -> None:
        self._sort = _sort

    @classmethod
    def from_list(
        cls,
        data: list[T0],
        *,
        depth: int | None = 2,
    ) -> Sort[T0, T0]:
        if len(data) <= 15:
            sort = SortMergeAll.from_list(data)
        elif len(data) <= 15:  # still looking into whether intense is good
            sort = SortMerge.from_intense(data)
        else:
            if depth is None:
                depth = int(math.log(len(data), 2))
                depth = max(2, depth - 4)
            sort = SortBin.from_list(data, depth=depth, sort=Sorted)  # type: ignore
        return sort

    @classmethod
    def from_sort(cls, sort: Sort[T0, T0]) -> Sorted[T0]:
        return cls(SortValuesCache(sort, [], False))  # type: ignore

    @functools.cached_property
    def run(self) -> ASortRun_[T, T]:
        yield from self._sort.run

    @property
    def values(self) -> list[T]:
        return self._sort.values

    def sort(self, cmp: Callable[[tuple[T, ...]], bool]) -> list[T]:
        it = self.run__compare
        try:
            _, values = next(it)
            while True:
                _, values = it.send(cmp(values))
        except StopIteration:
            pass
        return self._sort.values


################################
#                              #
# Some non-library 'test' code #
#                              #
################################

# Please note the code is just here as a 'here's what I was using to
# check the algorithms work' demonstration.
# 
# Given the lack of pytest and just poor quality of the code below.
# I don't really want a review from here and below.
# 
# Note: please uncomment the `## random.seed(42401)` comment left over
#       in the above code to ensure Sorted is stable.
#       SortMerge is _not_ stable and I'd prefer to use a simpler
#       algorithm than figure out another PITA algorithm.


def gen_test_object(sort_type: type[Sort[Any, Any]]) -> Sorted[int]:
    random.seed(42401)
    if issubclass(sort_type, SortValues):
        return Sorted.from_sort(SortValues.from_list([1, 6, 0, 2, 5, 3, 4]))
    if issubclass(sort_type, SortValuesCache):
        return Sorted.from_sort(SortValuesCache.from_list([1, 6, 0, 2, 5, 3, 4]))
    if issubclass(sort_type, SortMergeSource):
        return Sorted.from_sort(SortMergeSource(SortFirsts([SortValues([1, 6, 0, 2]), SortValues([5, 3, 4])], []), None, [], SortMergeAll))  # type: ignore
    if issubclass(sort_type, SortMergeAll):
        return Sorted.from_sort(SortMergeAll.from_list([1, 6, 0, 2, 5, 3, 4]))
    if issubclass(sort_type, SortMerge):
        return Sorted.from_sort(SortMerge.from_list([1, 6, 0, 2, 5, 3, 4]))
    if issubclass(sort_type, SortBin_):
        return Sorted.from_sort(SortBin_.from_list([1, 6, 0, 2, 5, 3, 4]))  # type: ignore
    if issubclass(sort_type, SortBin):
        n = 100
        return Sorted.from_sort(SortBin.from_list(random.sample(range(n), k=n), sort_tree=SortMergeAll))  # type: ignore
    if issubclass(sort_type, Sorted):
        n = 100
        return Sorted.from_sort(Sorted.from_list(random.sample(range(n), k=n)))
    raise TypeError(f"Unknown type: {sort_type.__name__}")


def cmp__int(vs: tuple[int, ...]) -> bool:
    assert 2 == len(vs)
    return vs[0] < vs[1]


def test_reload(sort: Sort[T, T], cmp: Callable[[tuple[T, ...]], bool]) -> bool:
    dump_a = sort.dumps()
    sort_a = SortValuesCache[T, T].loads(dump_a)
    sort_b = SortValuesCache[T, T].loads(dump_a)

    dumps: list[str] = [dump_a]
    values: list[tuple[int, ...]] = []

    it_a = sort_a.run__compare
    it_b = sort_b.run__compare
    i = 0
    try:
        _, values_a = next(it_a)
        _, values_b = next(it_b)
        values.append(values_a)  # type: ignore
        while True:
            if (values_a != values_b
                or sort_a.values != sort_b.values
            ):
                print(i, values_a, values_b, "\n", sort_a.values, "\n", sort_b.values)
                # for value in values:
                #     print(value)
                # print(sort_a)
                # print(sort_b)
                # print(sort_a.dumps() != sort_b.dumps())
                # for dump in dumps[-1:] + [sort_b.dumps(), sort_a.dumps()]:
                #     # print(dump)
                #     print(pretty_fmt(json.loads(dump)), "\n")
                return False
            dumps.append(sort_b.dumps())
            sort_b = SortValuesCache[T, T].loads(dumps[-1])
            it_b = sort_b.run__compare
            _, values_b = next(it_b)
            values.append(values_a)  # type: ignore
            assert values_a == values_b
            wanted = cmp(values_a)
            _, values_a = it_a.send(wanted)
            _, values_b = it_b.send(wanted)
            i += 1
    except StopIteration:
        pass
    return True


class StrReprless(str):
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return self.__str__()


def pretty_fmt(obj: Any) -> Any:
    if (isinstance(obj, dict)
        and "__name__" in obj
        and "kwargs" in obj
    ):
        name = obj["__name__"]  # type: ignore
        if (kwargs := obj["kwargs"]) is None:  # type: ignore
            return f"{name}"
        else:
            kwargs_ = ", ".join(
                f"{key}={pretty_fmt(value)}"
                for key, value in kwargs.items()  # type: ignore
            )
            return StrReprless(f"{name}({kwargs_})")
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        obj = {key: pretty_fmt(value) for key, value in obj.items()}  # type: ignore
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        obj = [pretty_fmt(value) for value in obj]  # type: ignore
    return obj


def main():
    SORT_TYPES = (SortValues, SortValuesCache, SortMergeSource, SortMerge, SortMergeAll, SortBin_, SortBin, Sorted)
    # SORT_TYPES = ()
    for sort_type in SORT_TYPES:
        sort_a = gen_test_object(sort_type)
        sort_b = gen_test_object(sort_type)
        print(f"{sort_type.__name__:<15} {str(test_reload(sort_a, cmp__int)):<5}", sort_b.sort(cmp__int))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        raise SystemExit(1) from None
```

Comment: "but I don't want back-to-back Ls" What's an L here, a less-liked song? If all you want is a resume-on-crash, wouldn't pickling the state every song be a more straight-forward solution?

Comment: @Mast Yes. Pickle is a good idea -- one I hadn't thought of. However, pickle can't pickle generator objects -- [example](https://gist.github.com/Peilonrayz/e2533b185fc954d1dd35b043bf7c1ba6). I presume the idea is to solve "The complicated part is having an algorithm which supports resuming from an arbitrary save point." Since pickling the generator isn't an option I can't think of a way to solve the issue with pickle which isn't really just identical to JSON. Can you?

Comment: Not without breaking the lazy evaluation benefits of a generator, no. If you work with a list instead and remember the position you're at, yes. You can properly pickle that. You don't need to store a tree or any of the other hard work, just the result. Update that every song and at most you'll be almost a song behind. Which you'd want to start over anyway after a power failure.

Comment: @Mast Lets focus on the bisect example. "If you work with a list instead and remember the position you're at", is what I already store when using `SortBisect`: `values`, `value`, `lo` and `hi`. Converting from JSON to pickle the `SortBisect` class _wouldn't change_, as all of the JSON handling is handled in the `Sort` base class. Have I misunderstood you?

Comment: I'd have to dig much, much deeper into your code to reliably answer that. I think I have a significantly different approach in mind than what you wrote here, but I have not tested yours. I simply took the information from description. The code is heavy on algorithms and less so on implementation details, I won't be able to review it either way. Far from my specialty.

Comment: @Mast "I think I have a significantly different approach" Ah! If you can show the approach with bisect alone then we can clean up the comments, and you probably can get some nice tasty rep :)

Comment: Perhaps this is me being naive: don't your tastes change over time or based on context? Would a ranking system that over-rotates a song not make you sick of it?

Comment: @Reinderien I was thinking of explaining my situation a bit more... but thought not to. Right now I listen to one genre in a 600 large playlist. I have another 1.4k playlist of the same genre. I have 1k+ songs in other Spotify playlists. I am missing lots of songs I used to listen to on YouTube (probably 1k+). So out of the songs I like I'm already down to 20%. The ranking is mostly to just have a large 90% filler content through the day, with a nice 10% when I am showering or listening to music. Additionally I want an 'accurate' ranking system for something which isn't just for songs.

Answer (score 0):

## downrev interpreter

```
from __future__ import annotations
```

The language has had annotations for quite some while.
If your goal is to target an
[unsupported](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Python#Table_of_versions)
EOL interpreter, then give us a hint, maybe with

```
assert sys.version_info >= (3, 7)
```

Consider adding

```
from collections.abc import Iterable
```

for type checking of iterables.

Feel free to elide the `-> None:` annotation
on `__init__` ctors, as `mypy` and humans know what's happening there.

## docstring

The global name `DSort` is maybe OK.
But the noun is ambiguous, so I would really appreciate having
a docstring spell out that you expect my mental pronunciation
to be "dict sort", or maybe "dump sort".
Maybe we wanted to end with an adjective of `DSorted`?

## @staticmethod

```
        ... , type(self).object_hook ...
```

That seems inconvenient.
Prefer to `def object_hook` at module level.
Or use a decorator on the current method.

```
    def object_hook(d: dict[str, Any]) -> Any:  # type: ignore
        if ("__name__" in d
            and "kwargs" in d
        ):
```

I don't understand what's going on here with type checking
plus explicit runtime check for a pair of keys.
Surely we wanted to accept only `DSort` inputs, right?

Also, annotating that we return a sort models class would be helpful.

I feel that mypy was trying to tell you that `return d` was not
appropriate, and it would be better to `raise` fatal error instead.

`JSONSortDecoder` would really benefit from a docstring which
[shows](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html)
examples of the two decoding cases.
A unit test that demonstrates roundtripping values would be nice.

## meaningful identifier

```
            STATE = state
```

This is clearly non-constant.

Prefer `initial_state`.

Also, these names are weird and I don't get what
the `__` dunder is trying to convey:

- `run__values`
- `run__compare`

Prefer

- `run_values`
- `run_compare`

I have no idea what the `from_intense()` name is all about.
If there's an elapsed time argument that the target or test code
wants to make, I didn't notice it.

## nouns for class names

```
class SortBisect ...
```

Prefer `SortBisector`.

Also, it looks like the (verbified!) `Sort` class
seems to be a `SortableMap`, something like that.

These are distinct names:

- `SortBin_`
- `SortBin`

They don't help the Gentle Reader draw a distinction
between their behaviors.
We conventionally use such a suffix when we want
to recycle an English word for a *new* concept
unrelated to the one already using that word,
e.g. `dir_ = '/tmp'` is quite different from `dir(int)`.
Tacking on a numeric suffix at least lets us
conveniently pronounce things over the phone.
Inventing entirely new names of SortBinFoo and SortBinBar
would be better, if a descriptive Foo can be found.

We're asking these unique identifiers to do some heavy lifting,
to describe themselves. Sometimes a concise identifier can do that.
Often we will need a one-sentence docstring to accomplish that.

## stability

I see some helpful comments:

```
        ## random.seed(42401)  # needed for Sorted to be stable
```

```
#       ... to ensure Sorted is stable.
#       SortMerge is _not_ stable ...
```

Alas, there's no docstrings,
so `sphinx` output won't be describing
this important algorithmic property.
The OP review context maybe offers a start on writing
some class Single Responsibility one-sentence docstrings.

This code does not yet have an emphasis
on clearly conveying technical ideas to collaborators.
That's as much of it as I will try to wade through for now.

---

## restartable computations

From the Review Context I assumed `(a, b)` comparisons are expensive
because they involve prompting a person for a `bool` result.
But I didn't notice any such prompting in the code.

The `(a, b)` comparisons evaluated so far induce a partial ordering.
If we store them along with the `list` of values and a `step` number,
then reproducing a generator which was in the middle of a sort
should be as simple as replaying the given number of steps.

Comment: "The language has had annotations for quite some while. If your goal is to target an unsupported EOL interpreter, then give us a hint, maybe with". [`from __future__ import annotations` has not been made mandatory in any Python version](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__future__.html#module-contents). "`from __future__ import annotations` was previously scheduled to become mandatory in Python 3.10, but the Python Steering Council twice decided to delay the change" -- [source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__future__.html#id2)

Comment: Also, linters like `mypy` keep telling me the `typing` module will be deprecated / removed in future. Avoiding `List` in favor of `list` is easy; `Iterable` from `collections` may be less obvious.

Comment: [I know](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62033243), and I use `--strict` mode which errors if you remove the `-> None`.